# Hide the Save button in lightning:unsavedChanges

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using the **[lightning:unsavedChanges](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation)**. I don't want to use the **Save** button.

I also tried with *display:none* but it didn't work. How can I remove or hide it? Thanks
[image]

Comment: If there's no documented way to do it, you won't be able to achieve what you are attempting to.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

in the css of the component, you can add

.THIS .slds-button-brand{
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
}

this will hide all of the brand buttons in that component

Comment: It didn't work and I don't want to hide all brand buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

inside your Aura component just add these lines

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .saveBtn {
    display: none;
    }
</aura:html>
```